# Undertow - SSL read loop detected when invoking microservice through k8s service

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-webflux, undertow

I've a *reactive* microservice application (we will call this microservice X) with the following dependencies: Spring Boot v2.2.8.RELEASE, SpringWebFlux v5.2.7.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.7.RELEASE,  Undertow core 2.0.30.Final, deploying it in a k8s environment.
In this environment, there is another microservice (we will call this microservice Y) sending an HTTP request to the microservice X; the call is made through the k8s service.
Randomly, it happens the following error when Y calls X:

**log of microservice Y**:

```
<microservice-Y-name>,7,[https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-2],ERROR,....
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://hostname.svc.k8s.xxx.com/<microservice-X-name>/api/tasks": Unexpected end of file from server; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:651)
```

**log of microservice X:**

```
SSL read loop detected. This should not happen, please report this to the Undertow developers. Current state SslConduit{state=20, outstandingTasks=0, wrappedData=null, dataToUnwrap=DefaultPooledBuffer{buffer=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=5461 lim=6026 cap=17408], referenceCount=1}, unwrappedData=null}
28-08-2020 07:43:24.514,microservice-X-name,7,[boundedElastic-3876],ERROR,c.w.o.o.w.d.HttpErrorHandler,,,,,,,,..... : {}
org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Request body is missing: ....
               at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.handleMissingBody(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:230)
               at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.lambda$readBody$5(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:194)
               at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:70)
```

**Changing the microservice Y configuration in order to invoke the microservice X via k8s ingress instead of via k8s service, the error never occurs.**

Any idea as of why this could happen?

Comment: and where are the k8 logs?

Comment: Ingress is working because it retries failed requests. When going directly to the service you don't have this retry mechanism inbetween. Please check whether this is the case. If so, most probably the problem is with your application. Let me know if you confirm it.